# Multiple wildcards in Apigee

Tags: apigee

I have a scenario where I need to have BAsepath in Apigee Edge gateway with multiple wild cards like this

api/vi/customer/{multiple words}

The Multiple words can be anything like below. If I use basepath as api/vi/customer/* .

- is accepting only one word and not multiple words. what is the solution if wildcard needs to be multiple words like below

api/vi/customer/**account/id?a=1**

api/vi/customer/**account/name**

api/vi/customer/**account/status**

Answer (score 0):

Here you are working in Apigee with two core concepts: Basepaths, and Proxy Endpoints.

api/vi/basepath/endpoint1

You have choices when it comes to wanting to support wildcards: you can set up a proxy on one core Basepath, but with multiple (or wild-card) proxy endpoints, or you can also set up separate Basepaths. The docs can help you understand the trade-offs.

Core proxy-routing docs: https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/fundamentals/understanding-routes

How to set up wild-card proxy Basepaths:
https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/reference/api-proxy-configuration-reference#proxyendpoint-proxyendpointconfigurationelements

Here's a related answer here on Stack Overflow from eight months ago: [Configure multiple base paths in APIGEE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65628982/configure-multiple-base-paths-in-apigee)